what should I do if lines appear when cutting with a knife?

I have been trying to delete these lines for so long, but I do not know how to do it, please help anyone who understands

See these answers: Eliminating edges connecting islands or this How can I remove jump lines created by boolean modifiers? and this Don't understand why holes needs to be connected to edge. It is not possible to create a hole without (at least) two connecting edges.

Hello, yuni, welcome to BSE.  this does look like a duplicate of questions previously answered well, so it's fair to close it out. Nothing personal. If the other answers are not satisfactory, go ahead and edit your post, explaining why, and we can re-open it for you.

@RobinBetts Stupid question on my behalf: when I vote to close a question and choose another question/answer as duplicate to link to, but later realize another question would have been better for answering (because here are so many with similar topics), can I somehow change my vote to select a different answer? Like in this example, now the link goes to what I first chose, but actually the link I give first in my comment seems to be better in my opinion.

Hi, @GordonBrinkmann .. Not stupid at all.  I can't think of a way. I could do an insta-open-and-reclose for you, but, since the other links are already in the comment .. (thanks for the choice BTW).. I think we can expect yuni to check them out anyway, so no great harm done?.

@RobinBetts No, not any great harm done. I was just taking this opportunity to ask for it since this happens every once in a while to me... I sometimes know there are better answers but just cannot find them.
